How can I fill a butt joint gap on exterior trim?
How do I correct the trim gaps on this?  It’s in a shed so not gonna replace it all.


even glue with fine sawdust will fill that.

For a small gap like that painter's caulk is just fine. If you'd rather have something firm and sandable, consult your local hardware or paint store and read labels. There are plenty of trowelable products to be found.
